# Как сделать поиск массиве и отображение в компоненте ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Как сделать поиск массиве и отображение в компоненте ComboBox? По примеру поисковика Google.

Код:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = null;
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    if ((e.KeyValue >= 34 && e.KeyValue <= 175))
    {
        string[] WRT1 = new string[] { "27", "Alex", "Gulynin1", "новый","сон"};
        string[] arr = new string[WRT1.Length];
        string str;
            if (comboBox1.Text != "")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < WRT1.Length; i++)
                {
                    str = WRT1[i];
                    if (str.IndexOf(comboBox1.Text) != -1)
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(WRT1[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Сейчас код не работает:

1. только со второго символа находит;
2. при нажатии клавиши отзеркаливается текст

Comment: а что с поисковиком гугла? Логика какая должна быть?

Comment: `if (str.StartsWith(comboBox1.Text))` ?

Comment: @tym32167 вводишь 'а' ,а в вкладке comboBox  появляется Alex

Comment: `if (str.ToLower().StartsWith(comboBox1.Text.ToLower()))` ?

Comment: ну или `if (str.ToLower().Contains(comboBox1.Text.ToLower()))` ?

Comment: Кажется есть свойство `autocomplette`. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Хорошо, что Вы приложили свой код. Но лучше при этом сразу рассказать, что с ним не так.

Comment: @defaultlocale 1. только со второго символа находит 2. при нажатии клавиши отзеркаливается текст

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это называется автодополнение.

### Автодополнение из элементов списка

Самый простой вариант: если нужно, чтобы так выбирался один из элементов списка. Его можно реализовать так:

1. Заполнить элементы списка `Items`:

   Это можно сделать как через конструктор так и через код

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "27",
            "Alex",
            "Gulynin1",
            "новый",
            "сон"
});
```

2. Установить свойству [`AutoCompleteMode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode?view=netframework-4.7.2) значение `SuggestsAppend` (предлагать и дополнять), а свойству [`AutoCompleteSourse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource?view=netframework-4.7.2) значение `ListItems` (выбирать из элементов списка).

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

В результате получим:

[image: Выпадающий список]

### Автодополнение из другого списка

Если нужно, чтобы в самом выпадающем списке был один набор элементов, а в автодополнении другой, то можете воспользоваться свойством [`AutoCompleteSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource?view=netframework-4.7.2). Такое поведение может понадобится если Ваш список поддерживает добавление новых элементов, например.

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(new string[] {
            "27",
            "Alex",
            "Gulynin1",
            "новый",
            "сон"});
//и заполняем соответствующие свойства
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

В результате получится похожее поведение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Добавление в список

Теперь можно по нажатию Enter добавлять выбранные элементы в выпадающий список ComboBox:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                var newString = comboBox1.Text;
                if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(newString))
                {
                    comboBox1.BeginUpdate();
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(newString);
                    comboBox1.EndUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
```

### Ошибки

> только со второго символа находит;

Это происходит потому что событие `KeyDown` выполняется сразу при нажатии на клавишу (например, `A`) еще до того как обновился текст. Т.о. в обработчике событий при нажатии «A» текст еще пустой и это условие не срабатывает:

```
if (comboBox1.Text != "")
```

Для того чтобы это исправить можете вместо события `KeyDown` обрабатывать событие `TextChanged` и уже не обрабатывать клавиши, а сразу действовать в зависимости от набранного текста.

> при нажатии клавиши отзеркаливается текст

Это происходит из-за того что при очистке списка

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
```

курсор автоматически устанавливается в начало строки. Этого можно избежать если для очистки использовать следующий метод ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731890/i-want-to-stop-combobox-items-clear-from-moving-my-text-cursor)):

```
public static void SafeClearItems(ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        foreach (var item in comboBox.Items.Cast<object>().ToList())
        {
            comboBox.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

Если исправить ошибки, то можно добиться нужного результата, но лучше и проще использовать стандартное автодополнение.

Answer (score 3):

Есть дефаулт свойства [`AutoComplete*`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Обратите внимание, все это можно реализовать из визуального конструктора, нет необходимости это делать в коде. Код для примера, как работает:

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
AutoCompleteStringCollection Raccolta = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
col.Add("Foo");
col.Add("Bar");
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Raccolta;
```

Автокомплит в конструкторе:

[image: Автокомплит в конструкторе]